# AWK if 3rd line starts with " merge it with second line

Tags: awk, gawk

I have some corrupted .txt files, in which I need to fix first 3 lines.

How it should be:

```
Template=1.0
SKU, Standard Price, Minimum Age Recommendation
sku, standard_prive, mg_recommendation
```

After it got corrupted:

```
Template=1.0
SKU, Standard Price, "Minimum Age Recommendation
"
sku, standard_prive, mg_recommendation
```

in some cases:

```
Template=1.0
SKU, Standard Price, "Minimum Age
" Recommendation
sku, standard_prive, mg_recommendation
```

I need to check if first line starts with quote mark, if yes, then merge 3rd line with second line.

otherwise I can't import the file as it fails to find proper headings in 3rd line.

AWK is preferred, because I already performing other task with it.
I can't figure out, how I could check 3rd line value while I'm on 2nd value in the awk loop.

Comment: How is your data getting corrupted?  It seems that the proper solution is to address that issue.

Comment: I understand your point, but if that would be possible I would do it as you say. Data is already corrupted, and only way to fix it is do it by fixing corrupted files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR==1||/^\"/?"":ORS),$0}' file
How it should be:

Template=1.0
SKU, Standard Price, Minimum Age Recommendation
sku, standard_prive, mg_recommendation

After it got corrupted:

Template=1.0
SKU, Standard Price, "Minimum Age Recommendation"
sku, standard_prive, mg_recommendation

in some cases:

Template=1.0
SKU, Standard Price, "Minimum Age" Recommendation
sku, standard_prive, mg_recommendation
```

Solution preceeds records that don't start with `"` with a newline. Downside is that the last record ends without a newline. `END{print ""}` fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

Aidas, could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /^\"/){printf("%s",Q);Q="";};print;Q=$0}'  Input_file
```

**EDIT:** Adding one more solution where it skips those lines in Input_file which are starting from string("). It wouldn't look for line number each line which starts from " it skips.

```
awk '/^\"$/{next} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Could you please add some explanations to it?

Comment: @AidasKeburys: my above code is working fine for me as follows it gives me output for your corrupted file.
awk '{if($0 ~ /^\"/){printf("%s",Q);Q="";};print;Q=$0}'   file1
Template=1.0
SKU, Standard Price, "Minimum Age
SKU, Standard Price, "Minimum Age" Recommendation
sku, standard_prive, mg_recommendation

Let me know if you have any queries on same, will try to sort it out then.

Comment: The expected output is the first block in the question, under "How it should be:".

Comment: @jas, thank you for letting me know. I am pretty sure OP has changed his/her requirement as I saw like OP wanted to put " string into the previous line so I had given that solution accordingly, let me redefine my solution now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk like this:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==2 {sub(/"/,"")} FNR==3 && $0 ="\"" {next} 1' yourfile > convertedfile
```

- on line 2 it replace quote with nothing
- for line3 if it is a single qoute it skips this line

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/\"/,"")}NF' file 

Template=1.0
SKU, Standard Price, Minimum Age Recommendation
sku, standard_prive, mg_recommendation
```